# Only display else block if ALL options in *ngIf fail to be true

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have multiple options in an `*ngIf` seperated by the `||` operator. I also have a `else` operator setup to show if nothing is true. Problem is, it displays the else block on each operation rather than overall.

**NgIf Block with ngFor**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
     <div *ngIf="sortBy && sortByColor && sortCategory.color == expense.category.color || sortBy && sortByTitle && sortCategory.title == expense.category.title || !sortBy; else elseBlock>
         ....
     </div>
     <ng-template #elseBlock>
         <p>This is the else block that should show up only when nothing is displayed above.</p>
     </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

I only want the else block to show up if nothing is displayed in the ngFor at all based on the paramaters set forth in the `ngIf` instead right now it displays the else on each run of `ngFor`.

Comment: Did you try moving the <ng-template> outside of the ngFor ?

Comment: I just did and it still provides the same results. It displays for each hidden card rather than displaying only when the entire DIV is empty (no NgIf's are true)

Comment: ok try this: with ng-template being inside ngFor and then outside and see `*ngIf="(sortBy && sortByColor && sortCategory.color == expense.category.color) || (sortBy && sortByTitle && sortCategory.title == expense.category.title) || !sortBy; else elseBlock`

Comment: Interesting, if the `ng-template` is inside the `ngFor` it never appears however, if you place it outside the `ngFor` then it appears for each card that is not displayed.

Comment: that's because the else block is triggered inside the ngFor and as long as the loop runs it will keep rendering that else block when condition is met

Comment: I just want to show a simple "no results matched those filters" message when nothing is displayed. If someone could provide me that code or point me in the RIGHT direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: When those filters are set ? is it after you get the expenses list ?

Comment: Yes, the filters are modified in the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have only one `elseBlock` displayed, you should put it outside of the `ngFor` loop, in an outer `ngIf` condition. If you put the condition in a method of the component defined as an arrow function:

```
isSortedExpense = (expense) => {
  return !this.sortBy ||
    this.sortByColor && this.sortCategory.color == expense.category.color || 
    this.sortByTitle && this.sortCategory.title == expense.category.title;
}
```

you can call it in the outer `ngIf` and in the inner `ngIf`. The presence of at least one displayed item can be tested with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="expenses?.some(isSortedExpense); else elseBlock"> 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
     <div *ngIf="isSortedExpense(expense)">
       ....
     </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <p>This is the else block that should show up only when nothing is displayed above.</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This does the trick. Yet, for some reason I get six of these errors in my console. `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

Comment: I added the safe navigation operator `?.` in `expenses?.some(...)` to account for cases where `expenses` is not yet defined.